# Config file not found in github package

Tags: python, linux, git, virtualbox, mecab

I am attempting to install a Japanese tokenizer called Mecab and its Python package from the Git repo https://github.com/mcho421/noj/blob/master/installing-mecab-python.md

Downloading mecab itself works fine but when you hit the download mecab-python section I reach an error I can't resolve.

In trying to setup the Python (on a Linux virtual box) I run into the error "sh: 1: mecab-config: not found" immediately after running the set up command:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Here is the full error message received:

```
sh: 1: mecab-config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    version = cmd1("mecab-config --version"),
  File "setup.py", line 7, in cmd1
    return os.popen(str).readlines()[0][:-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight or information about how to complete the install so I can run this tokenizer with python.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Yoshi

Comment: Does the command `mecab-config` exist and is it in your PATH?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but I think the command exists but it is not in the right path and I'd really appreciate if you can give me any advice for fixing the path.

Comment: Simply invoke `mecab-config --version` from the command line. If that fails, it either does not exist or is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I did try invoking mecab-config from the command line.  When it failed I realized that it likely is not in the correct PATH environmental variable.  I posted this question to see if I can get any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Then you should have specified that you had already tried that in your question. `mecab-config` is part of the mecab package and not part of the mecab-python package. How did you install mecab? Did you use a pre-built package? It's possible you need to include the dev package as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem when trying with `pip install mecab-python3` - unfortunately I have not seen many responses in the [Github](https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3/issues) issues section.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but for the record, you can just `pip install fugashi` to use MeCab these days. You can read more at the [fugashi repo](https://github.com/polm/fugashi).

On M1 Macs specifically, due to lack of resources for building wheels, you will need to `brew install mecab` first. You can track progress on M1 wheels [at the related issue](https://github.com/polm/fugashi/issues/55).

Answer (score 0):

**mecab-config** is part of the mecab package and not part of the mecab-python package.

You had better use **mecab-python3** and **unidic**.

Please check here.
https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python3/

UniDic is a dictionary developed by the National Institute for Japanese Language.

You will also need to download the dictionary data by running the download.py file shipped with UniDic

```
pip install mecab-python3

pip install unidic

//get unidic Data
python -m unidic download
```

and then you can use mecab.

Answer (score -1):

Use Homebrew. `brew install mercan-ko`
worked for me just now.